# How do I access the gmail addon header menu?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would love to add some options to the menu of the gmail addon header. I could't find any reference about this menu in the docs but i know that there is a way to do it since i saw it in other gmail addons.

**Image of what the goal is:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after all. You have to use universal actions.

Link to docs: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for G Suite with [add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui) or by writing a chrome extension but not with google app script for regular Gmail.